# list all users of all applications DATABASE SQL

Tags: sql, database

I have two tables in my database, `Application` and `User`.

The `Application` table has columns `id_app` and `name_app`, and the `User` table has `id_user` and `name_user`.

Between these two tables, I have an association with a column `date_registration`.

An application can have 1 to n users. And each user can be registered in 1 or n applications.

I want to list all users of all application with the date of the registration. How can I do that?

Note: I'm developing a Java application and I want to show all this data in a Jtable.

Comment: are you storing the date of registration?

Comment: what table holds the relationship between applications and users? You indicate that the APPLICATION table seemingly has just one row per application, with columns ID_APP and NAME_APP. Considering the USER table has just two columns, ID_USER, NAME_USER, I don't see any way -- based on the info you've given -- to determine what users use which applications.

Comment: Yes I'm storing the date of registration. The table that holds the relationship between applicationns and users contains : id_app , id_user and date_registration

Answer (score 0):

This should be what you need:

```
select u.id_user, u.name_user, a.id_app, a.name_app, r.date_registration
  from application a
  join table3 r
    on a.id_user = r.id_user
  join user u
    on a.id_user = u.id_user
```

(I've given the third table that you mention in your comments -- the one that relates users with applications -- a name of "table3" (rename accordingly))

Comment: Thank u so much for ur help, i'm going to try it.

Comment: Can u please tell how to insert all the data ( at the same time ). I want to insert for example an user and the application he is registered in and also the date of registration.